# How to design credit system for a subscription service that uses Stripe for payment

Tags: architecture, stripe-payments

I am building an application which uses credits for keeping track of usage. I am looking for advice on how to design part of the system which revoles around the credits.

Goal:

A user will sign up to a plan which is either free forever or a 14 day trial. Upon inital signup depending on the plan a certain number of credits should be added to the user's account info (not actually as I have another way of tracking but to make simple assume the user's account). I need the customer's credit count to increase by the amount their plan dictates when their subscription renews.

Stack:

- Node.js
- Express.js
- MongoDB
- Stripe

Current thoughts for how to do this:

Stripe has different webhooks, one of which is `invoice.payment_succeeded` which I can add in a webhook endpoint for and have them send me notifications when a payment succeeded (according to Stripe it is: `Occurs whenever an invoice payment attempt succeeds`).

I was thinking of having a script that would be triggered upon recieving this webhook and would look at the customer's plan and would update their credit count accordingly.

Does this seem like a good solution to get what I want or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Same situation, invoice_paid seems to be great. Problem is what do you do for yearly plans with a one time payement ? Can't really figure it out. Did you use a cron or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `invoice.paid` event to indicate when the invoice moves to `status=paid` as a simpler signal, but broadly your approach matches what i was going to recommend:

1. Track this credit/balance on your own system
2. Assign suitable credits per pricing plan
3. Listen to invoice webhooks and add the correct amount of credit to the correct account balance
4. Reduce credit balance as your user consumes services.
5. If necessary, trigger early renewal or one-off payments to top-up balance if depleted before renewal.

Comment: Looks like the difference between the webhook I said and you did is, `invoice is marked as paid out-of-band`, does this make a difference and where would it occur? As for the rest of what you said I think it lines up well with what I had in mind as a end goal as well as my rough plan.

Comment: "Occurs whenever an invoice payment attempt succeeds *or* an invoice is marked as paid out-of-band." It includes both :) (payment success event will miss paid OOB invoices)

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to handle monthly credit refills with annual plans ?